# Firebase AUTH won't stay logged in

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I log into a firebase app using `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`, the user is logged in. Then, if I reload the page, the user is no longer logged in. If I go to another webpage with the same firebase apiKey and everything, the user still isn't logged in. How would I go about making sure the user stays logged in until `firebase.auth().signOut()` is called?

Comment: A quick guess is that you're not monitoring authentication state (see [the docs for that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)). If that's not it, please share the [minimal, complete code that allows us to reproduce your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Turns out I was just trying to get `firebase.auth().currentUser` without the state change monitor. I took your advice and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Also, to whomever close-voted it, how is it off-topic? Please elaborate.

Comment: It works after my small comment. I didn't feel it worth an answer (since I'm pretty sure I've pointed the same out in the past few days), so voted to close as it is unlikely others will find this one.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Okay, should I delete it then?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen's comment helped me. I think a full answer would be helpful to future seekers.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino It would be great if you answer your own post, so that if someone else has same issue he can find out the solution without reading thread of commets

Comment: @RezaRahmati Sure, I will do that. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply using `firebase.auth().currentUser` usually won't work because when that's loaded, Firebase usually hasn't authenticated and connected a user account yet. Instead, wait for the authorization state to change using `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(func)` where `func` is called when the auth state is changed (which could mean signing in or signing out or switching accounts).

Comment: Yes... exactly... I'm using `onAuthStateChanged` and it keeps randomly firing to say the user is null. I never told it to sign out, it just does it by itself which messes up my app.

Comment: @JeneralJames i have the same issue. Were you able to fix it?